# Class that can be used through out application

Tags: c#

Noob question here, but I'm really stuck!

I'm trying to establish a class that can be used though out my application called `UpdateDatabase`. The `UpdateDatabase.cs` file is stored in my `AppName.Helpers`namespace and I've declared `using AppName.Helpers` everywhere I want to use `UpdateDatabase`.

I'm having trouble calling `UpdateDatabase`. I've set it as a `public class UpdateDatabase`. Is that the right thing to do?

Within `UpdateDatabase` I have several other classes `UpdateCustomers`, `UpdateEmployees` and `UpdateProducts`. I would like for a user to be able to click a button, have that call `UpdateDatabase` and then begin executing the three "sub classes" in `UpdateDatabase`.

Everywhere that I call `UpdateDatabase` I get an error saying `AppName.Helpers.UpdateDatabase' is a 'type' but is used like a 'variable`

Comment: Please post the code that's giving you the errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're probably trying to do something like this:

`UpdateDatabase.UpdateCustomers();`

You have a few options here:

1) Create an object of the class

```
var helper = new UpdateDatabase();
helper.UpdateCustomers();
```

2) Use it as a static class

```
public static class UpdateDatabase {
    public static void UpdateDatabase(){}
}
```

In order to use a class's methods you have to create an instance of it so you access those methods. Or you can make it static so no instance is required, but then this class will be shared troughout every use of it.

If this does not answer your question you'll have to edit your post with code.

Comment: Thanks, it worked! I just did your first method and created an object of the class. Helps out a lot! :)

Answer (score 2):

I'm no C# programmer but it sounds to me like you need to *instantiate* your class.  Your class `updateDatabase` merely tells the compiler how that variable will look rather than it actually being an *object* of type `updateDatabase`.

In most OO languages you would create an object of type `myClass` by calling its *constructor* which happens implicitly when you use the `new` keyword.

Thus

```
var db = new updateDatabase();
db.myMethod();
```

For those reasons the compiler is complaining with the message

> `AppName.Helpers.UpdateDatabase' is a 'type' but is used like a 'variable`

Answer (score 1):

It would be helpful if you could show a bit of the code and its usage.
I am assuming the problem is that `UpdateDatabase` class is not a static class and/or that you have not created an instance of it by "newing it up", so that you can actually use it in other parts of your code.

Answer (score 0):

For the onClick of event of the button call your class like so:

```
UpdateDatabase.subclass();
```

Answer (score 0):

It's OK, everybody here was a nooblet once. =)

I do believe that your problem lies on the fact that you are trying to access the methods directly.

[According to MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yzh058ae.aspx), marking a class as public '[...] is the most permissive access level. There are no restrictions on accessing public members.' But you need to **instantiate** the class, like this:

```
    AppName.Helpers.UpdateDatabase _obj = new AppName.Helpers.UpdateDatabase();
```

After that, you'll be able to use its members (methods and properties).

On the other hand, you may declare your class as **[static](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/98f28cdx.aspx)**. You won't need instantiate it, but you won't be able to create an instance, and it can't be destroyed as well.